# What is the difference between single bracket df["column"] and double bracket df[["column"]]

Tags: python, pandas

One is a `pandas.core.series.Series` and another is a dataframe `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

I have seen codes using them both. Is there a guideline on when to use which?

Comment: A dataframe with one column is not the same as a `Series`. Certain operations can be performed on series, and not on dataframes (directly) and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be more specific, `df['column']` returns only one column, but when you use `df[['column']]` you can call more than one column.

for example `df[['column1','column2']]` returns `column1` and `column2` from `df`